# JMapper convert child Collection<Entity> to Collection<Dto>

Tags: jmap

I'm try to convert **DemoEntity** to **DemoDto**. And they have child attribute `Collection<SubEntity>` and `Collection<SubDto>`. Error happened when converting `Collection<SubEntity>`. If I don't add `@JMap("subEntities")`, JMapper would works well. Now I want that when converting `DemoEntity`, the `Collection<SubEntity>` could be converted together.

```html
public class DemoEntity {

    /** The id. */

    private int id;

    /** The code. */
    private String code;

    /** The date. */
    private Date date;

    private Collection<SubEntity> subEntities;

    @JMapConversion(from = "date", to = "date")
    public String convertDate(Date date) {
        return date.toString();
    }

    public DemoEntity(int id, String code, Date date, Collection<SubEntity> subEntities) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.date = date;
        this.subEntities = subEntities;
    }
  

    ...setter and getter...
}
```

```html
public class DemoDto {

    /** The id. */
    @JMap
    private Long id;

    /** The code. */
    @JMap
    private String code;

    /** The date. */
    @JMap
    private String date;

    @JMap("subEntities")
    private Collection<SubDto> subDtos;

  ... setter and getter...
}
```

**The main method is below:**

```html
        Collection<SubEntity> subEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            SubEntity subEntity = new SubEntity(i, "C" + i, new Date());
            subEntities.add(subEntity);
        }
        DemoEntity demoEntity = new DemoEntity(1, "D" + 1, new Date(), subEntities);


        JMapperAPI api = new JMapperAPI();
        MappedClass mappedClass = new MappedClass(SubDto.class);
        api.add(mappedClass);
        JMapper<DemoDto, DemoEntity> mapper = new JMapper<>(DemoDto.class, DemoEntity.class, api);
        DemoDto demoDto = mapper.getDestination(demoEntity);
        System.out.println(demoDto);
```

An exception happened, when covert **DemoEntity.subEntities** to **DemoDto.subDtos**

```html
Exception in thread "main" com.googlecode.jmapper.exceptions.JMapperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.config.JmapperLog.ERROR(JmapperLog.java:46)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.<init>(JMapper.java:445)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.<init>(JMapper.java:411)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.<init>(JMapper.java:385)
 at com.jmapper.JmapperDemo.main(JmapperDemo.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.operations.complex.AComplexOperation.newInstance(AComplexOperation.java:107)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.operations.complex.AComplexOperation.newInstance(AComplexOperation.java:98)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.operations.recursive.MappedCollectionOperation.sharedCode(MappedCollectionOperation.java:64)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.operations.complex.AComplexOperation.sourceControl(AComplexOperation.java:156)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.operations.complex.AComplexOperation.genericFlow(AComplexOperation.java:133)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.operations.complex.AComplexOperation.write(AComplexOperation.java:89)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.generation.MapperConstructor.mapping(MapperConstructor.java:154)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.generation.MapperConstructor.wrappedMapping(MapperConstructor.java:123)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.generation.MapperConstructor.getMappings(MapperConstructor.java:89)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.generation.MapperGenerator.generateMapperClass(MapperGenerator.java:54)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.generation.MapperBuilder.generate(MapperBuilder.java:88)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.createMapper(JMapper.java:458)
 at com.googlecode.jmapper.JMapper.<init>(JMapper.java:440)
 ... 3 more
```

Besides, is there any method convert `Collection<Entity>` to `Collection<Dto>`

Comment: I have `List<Pojo>` as source and `List<DTO>` as destination. Can I use JMapper to map source to destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of recursive mapping, you need to map sub classes.
As you map DemoDTO with DemoEntity, you need to map SubDTO with SubEntity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use like that. It works. But finally, I use MapStruct, since it is faster.